# Ruby - undefined method `extract_options!' : Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, tweetstream

While running following sample using [TweetStream](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream) I am getting mentioned error.

**tweets.rb**

```
require 'tweetstream'

TweetStream.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key       = '<CONSUMER KEY>'
  config.consumer_secret    = '<CONSUMER SECRET>'
  config.oauth_token        = '<OAUTH TOKEN>'
  config.oauth_token_secret = '<OAUTH TOKEN SECRET'
  config.auth_method        = :oauth
end

TweetStream::Client.new.track('ruby') do |status|
  puts "#{status.text}"
end
```

**Error**

```
$ ruby tweets.rb 
/home/amit/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/tweetstream-2.3.0/lib/tweetstream/client.rb:96:in `track': undefined method `extract_options!' for ["ruby"]:Array (NoMethodError)
        from tweets.rb:11:in `<main>'
    https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`extract_options!` is [ActiveSupport](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Array/ExtractOptions/extract_options!) method. If it's not rails app you need to install it and include into script.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Actually [this commit message](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream/commit/a63942dec7099efc74bc3d6bdae76a287de1d0ef) was stopping me to explore elsewhere in rails.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another solution: opening up `Array` class and defining `extract_options!` method on it.

Add the following code :

```
class Array
  def extract_options!
    last.is_a?(::Hash) ? pop : {}
  end unless defined? Array.new.extract_options!
end
```

to the beginning of the `tweets.rb` file or to a separate file (which would
need to be required in the `tweets.rb` file).

Comment: I Like this solution. Including ActiveSupport if you don't need it for anything else is not the way to go.

Comment: [Rails implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options.rb)

Answer (score 1):

I am too late to answer but i think it'll be useful for ruby naive programmers like me.

To include ActiveSupport method like *extract_options!*, you need to include Active Support.

> require 'active_support'

And if you want to include ruby gems then include rubygems too.

> require 'rubygems'